Rust - Axum cannot get "x-api-key" from request headers
I want the request headers to have the correct api key, but I can't get the api key from the request headers, my current Rust code:
fn app() -> Router<Arc<AppState>> {
    let cors = CorsLayer::new()
        .allow_origin(Any)
        .allow_methods(vec![Method::GET])
        .allow_headers(Any);

    Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .layer(cors)
        .layer(middleware::from_fn(auth_middleware))
}

async fn auth_middleware(req: Request, next: Next) -> Response {
    if let Some(api_key) = req.headers().get("x-api-key") {
        println!("{:?}", api_key);

        if api_key == "Test" {
            return next.run(req).await;
        }
    }

    (StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized").into_response()
}

req.headers().get("x-api-key") always returns None
I have tried sending requests from the frontend many times with the following code:
const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

const fetchFromApi = (query, filters) => {
    const headers = {
        "x-api-key": "Test",
    };
    
    const params = {
        query: query,
        fuzzy: filters.fuzzy,
        text: false,
    };
    
    const config = {
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
    };
    
    return axios.get(API_URL, config).then(response =\> response.data\["items"\]);
};

params is correct, headers looks fine but still doesn't solve the problem
What is the problem?

what is in the headers() - can you run w/ a debugger?

what i get when print headers() {"host": "127.0.0.1:8000", "connection": "keep-alive", "accept": "*/*", "access-control-request-method": "GET", "access-control-request-headers": "x-api-key", "origin": "http://localhost:5173", "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", "sec-fetch-mode": "cors", "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site", "sec-fetch-dest": "empty", "referer": "http://localhost:5173/", "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd", "accept-language": "vi-VN,vi;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5"}

Before sending your request, the browser will send a CORS preflight request that contains details about the endpoint (method, headers, etc.) that you want to call. The CorsLayer will automatically handle this for you but your authentication middleware is rejecting it before getting there.
Order your middleware such that CORS is listed after your authentication function.
    Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .layer(middleware::from_fn(auth_middleware)) // switch
        .layer(cors)                                 // the order

This will make the cors middleware will handle the request before your authentication (.layer() calls work in reverse order).
